# nginx virtual hosts are not working, all vhosts goes to the default one

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nginx, virtualhost

I just did a clean install of nginx + php-fpm on a VPS running Ubuntu 10.10, nginx is serving and PHP is working fine, but I'm not able to add vhosts to it. Well, I can add them, but only one works, the rest go to this first one.

This is my first vhost, for host1:

```
server {

    listen   80;
    server_name host1;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/host1.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/host1.error.log;

    location / {
        root  /var/www/vhosts/host1/;
        index  index.html index.htm index.php;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        #fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_pass  unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /var/www/vhosts/host1/$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
    }
}
```

And the second one, for host2:

```
server {

    listen   80;
    server_name host2;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/host2.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/host2.error.log;

    location / {
        root  /var/www/vhosts/host2/;
        index  index.html index.htm index.php;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        #fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_pass  unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /var/www/vhosts/host2/$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
    }
}
```

The problem is, when I go to http://host1 everything is fine, but on http://host2, it just shows host1!

I don't have Apache installed and everything comes from repos. Any pointers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know what you have wrong, but take a look at my conf file, it worked.

```
server {
    server_name localhost;
    root /opt/local/html;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /opt/local/html/$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        /opt/local/etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf;
    }        
}


server {
    server_name  pma;
    root /opt/local/www/pma;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /opt/local/www/pma/$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        /opt/local/etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf;
    }
}
```